# Кто-нибудь может объяснить в деталях, что делает этот код?

Tags: c, математика, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

```
long int fib ( int n) {
    if (n==0)
        return 0;  
    else if (n==1)  
        return 1; 
    else 
        return (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробую "объяснить в детях"

```
long int fib ( int n) {     // Дите первое - объявление функции 
                            // вычисления n-го числа Фибоначчи

    if (n==0) return 0;       // Если это нулевое число - то оно нуль, возвращаем

    else if (n==1) return 1;   // Первое - единица, тоже возвращаем

    else return (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2));  // Все остальные вычисляются по
                                      // формуле как сумма двух предыдущих

    }
```

Все. Только считать будет для реальных `n` - скажем, 50 - неимоверно долго. Потому что на каждом шаге - раздвоение рекурсии, так что получим время `O(2^N)` - почти вечно...

Скажем, для `n=3` вызов приведет к возврату

```
fib(2)+fib(1);
```

При этом `fib(1)` считается сразу - равно `1`. `fib(2)` приводит к расчету

```
fib(1)+fib(0);
```

Эти значения вычисляются сразу и дают `1`. Возврат из рекурсии вверх - и получаем `fib(3)` равным `1+1=2`.

Лучше делать функцию от беззнакового аргумента, потому как при отрицательных значениях попадем в бесконечную рекурсию.

Comment: Наверное надо добавить, что нету защиты от отрицательных значений fib(-1) выдаст stack overflow

Comment: @goldstar_labs Спасибо, дописал.

Answer (score 1):

К вопросу о некотором улучшении данного кода:

```
uint64_t fib(const uint64_t n)
{
     return n<=1 ? n : fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Здесь мы:

- во-первых, используем 64 битное беззнаковое число, которое хранит числа до примерно `10^18` (`2^64-1` точно),
- во вторых, помечаем полученный параметр `const`, что является правилом хорошего тона для программирования вообще - важно помечать неизменяемые сущности таковыми. Это дает разработчику защиту в виде обнаружения нарушений логики (перезапись константы) уже на этапе компиляции программы.
- в-третьих, мы используем тернарное условие, что делает запись программы более лаконичной
- далее, мы в этом условии заменяем два сравнения одним, что опять же, сокращает код и уменьшает нагрузку на процессор (если оптимизатор не справится)

[Пример на ideone](https://ideone.com/jHMUvs)

В примере приводится расчет 93-го числа Фибоначчи, это самое большое число, которое можно вычислить, используя 64 битную арифметику.

Также, мне пришлось в примере схитрить и взять `C++` для того, чтобы заставить компилятор вычислить число Фибоначчи во время компиляции программы (ключевое слово `constexpr`) - в [случае с `C`](https://ideone.com/v2rJ4C) - сайт отказывается считать, ругаясь на превышение времени.

Программа должна выдать число `12200160415121876738`. В этом можно убедиться, вычислив то же самое число при помощи математического пакета `MAXIMA`, который использует длинную арифметику - заходим на [онлайн-версию](http://maxima.cesga.es) пакета и даем команду `fib(93);` - получаем наше число. С помощью той же `MAXIMA` можно найти, что `fib(94)` уже не влезет в `uint64_t`, для этого достаточно проверить, что выражение `fib(94) - (2^64 - 1)` положительно, следовательно, уменьшаемое `fib(94)` превосходит вычитаемое `(2^64-1)`.

Comment: У вас fib(93) и не вычислится ни за какое реальное время - это классический пример, как не надо писать рекурсию, там выходит O(2^N). Компилятор вычисляет просто потому что он достаточно умный и делает мемоизацию.

Comment: Да, об этом написано в тексте ответа, в чем претензия-то?

Comment: Вы написали "Программа должна выдать число 12200160415121876738" - не выдаст. Этого вы не написали. Из вашего текста получается, что просто надо немного подождать...

Comment: Выдаст. Зайдите на ideone и посмотрите. Компилятор все просчитывает на этапе компиляции и выдает программу с зашитой константой.

Comment: Напишите `cin >> n; cout << fin(n);` введите 93 и посмотрите на результат. Только не меняйте сам код функции.

Comment: О том что реальная попытка вычислить значение в рантайме будет провальной, написано прямо у меня в тексте. Там же написано, что если схитрить и свалить расчеты на компилятор, вычисления пройдут без проблем.
Таким образом можно подловить кого-нибудь на собеседовании - если соискатель начнет задвигать про O(N^2) и не заметит constexpr, можно задать ему дополнительный вопрос - почему же мой пример всегда работает.